# Roslaunch Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, roslaunch, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hey,

i am getting a new type of error which i am not aware of how to resolve it.... if anyone knows how to reolve this issue please let me know... the error message i am receiving is :

```
youbot@youbot-laptop:~$ roslaunch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roslaunch", line 2, in <module>
   from ros import roslaunch
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 57, in __getattr__
    return __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named roslaunch
```

if anyone has any idea regarding this please let me know...thanks in advance....

regards,

Maneesh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11780/roslaunch-traceback-(most-recent-call-last)/) by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
along with the above lines, I had few more lines of error, i read somewhere that, if you delete the .pyc file and change the name of the .py file the error goes off, and it did... was that the right solution???? Well i tried the same thing with above and it didnt work...

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
Hey thanks for responding, the output of the export PYTHONPATH=${ROS_ROOT}/core/roslib/src:${PYTHONPATH}, and yes after the ros setup, I am adding a line " $export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/youbot/ros_stacks" in the setup.sh

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-11-02**:
Sounds like problems with the python path. What does a "echo $PYTHONPATH" output? Are you changing PYTHONPATH after sourcing the ros setup file in your ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you redefined $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH so it no longer includes the stacks of the ROS distribution. That could explain your import failure.

The root problem seems to be misunderstanding environment variables, so here is the corrected `export` command, as explained in several comments below:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/maneesh/ros_stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-03**:
If this answer fixes your problem, please check (accept) it. For a new question, please open a new page.

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
Now, i am able to run the process.... but i seems to have a problem regarding the command, rosmake...., for example When i type" $rosmake youbot_oodl" I get an error stating:  [ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names. So what does that mean now???

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
Thank you so much for your help guys, it seems to be working fine now..... the process works....:)

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-11-03**:
As others have noted, you need to *append* to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  The sample you pasted *redefines* it.  Append looks like "export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/maneesh/ros_stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH"

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
and the last line was : if [ ! "$ROS_MASTER_URI" ] ; then export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 ; fi                                                                       now please let me know what i need to modify in order to get rid of this error....:)

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/diamondback/ros
export PATH=${ROS_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}
export PYTHONPATH=${ROS_ROOT}/core/roslib/src:${PYTHONPATH}
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/maneesh/ros_stacks

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
Yes, i tried that, but still i am getting the error... let me post the contents of the setup.sh file, that might help...

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-11-03**:
You must keep the original ROS_PACKAGE_PATH and prepend or append to it. Use: export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/youbot/ros_stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
I dint delete any line or path from the setup.sh, just added an additional line, which is export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/youbot/ros_stacks..... however, there was another line : export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks....which still present in the setup.sh.... is this causing the problem?

**Comment by [Maneesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/1287/maneesh/) on 2011-11-03**:
So how do i go about eliminating this failure / error, so that i can go ahead and launch gazebo with the ros command.... I am sorry, i am very much new to this and I have less knowledge in this field... if you can help with this, it would be grateful....

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-11-16**:
I see the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module>
    import roslaunch
ImportError: No module named roslaunch
```